# How to include dependencies in .NET Core app docker image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to build a .NET Core app docker image. But I can't figure out how I'm supposed to get the project's NuGet dependencies into the image.

For simplicity reasons I've create a .NET Core console application:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleCoreTestApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello World: {JsonConvert.False}");
        }
    }
}
```

It just has one NuGet dependency on `Newtonsoft.Json`. When I run the app from Visual Studio, everything works fine.

However, when I create a Docker image from the project and try to execute the app from there, it can't find the dependency:

```
# dotnet ConsoleCoreTestApp.dll
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'Newtonsoft.Json', version: '9.0.1', path: 'lib/netstandard1.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

This is to be expected because `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` is not being copied by Visual Studio to the output folder.

Here's the `Dockerfile` I'm using:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-core
COPY bin/Debug /app
```

Is there a recommended way of dealing with this problem?

I don't want to run `dotnet restore` inside of the container (as I don't want to re-download all dependencies everytime the container runs).

I guess I could add a `RUN dotnet restore` entry to the `Dockerfile` but then I couldn't use `microsoft/dotnet:<version>-core` as base image anymore.

And I couldn't find a way to make Visual Studio copy all dependencies into the output folder (like it does with regular .NET Framework projects).

Comment: I'm not a .net person so forgive my ignorance... Why does adding a `RUN dotnet restore` prevent you from using the dotnet base image?

Comment: @Matt is correct, it shouldn't prevent you from using the `microsoft/dotnet` base image.

Comment: @Matt Because the core image doesn't contain the restore command.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski oic.. so like a jre instead of jdk. Missing some dev bits.

Comment: @Matt Yes, it's like this. The core image is just the runtime.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some more reading I finally figured it out.

Instead of `dotnet build` you run:

```
dotnet publish
```

This will place all files (including dependencies) in a `publish` folder. And this folder then can be used directly with a `microsoft/dotnet:<version>-core` image.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [tutorial](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-deploy-asp-net-core-on-linux-with-docker) on this recently. The Dockerfile contents I used were (slightly modified to remove the ASP.NET Core bits):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

When you run `docker build`, it uses the Dockerfile as a "recipe" to build the image. It'll run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` first, *then* package everything up into the image. The resulting image has everything the app needs to run on any Docker host.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with a `dotnet:xxx-core` image. I'm not sure, though, whether the difference between `dotnet` and `dotnet:xxx-core` as base image is relevant.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski Just curious, why do you want to use `dotnet:xxx-core` instead of `dotnet:latest`?

Comment: No special reason. It seemed to most logical/minimal solution to me. Also, I'm trying not to put the source code in the container.