# Cannot find Application Insights dependency in docker image after dotnet publish

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run my application from a docker image:

```
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '1.0.2', path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
```

The docker image is based on `microsoft/aspnetcore`.

The files where built using `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish` on the docker image `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.0-projectjson`

Under `"targets"` in `{app}.deps.json` I have:

```
  "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/1.0.2": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.1",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter": "1.0.0",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
      "System.Net.NameResolution": "4.3.0"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll": {}
    },
    "compile": {
      "lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll": {}
    }
  },
```

I do not have a `lib` folder in my published output but I do have `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` at the root of my published output.

I feel like i'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Updating Application Insights to 2.0.0 has no effect.

Removing Application Insights simply moves the problem to another assembly.

Switching to a standalone deployment has no effect.

Added `COREHOST_TRACE=1` and received the following output:

```
Processing TPA for deps entry [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore, 2.0.0, lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll]
  Considering entry [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll] and probe dir [/packagescache/x64]
The hash file is invalid [/packagescache/x64/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.0.0/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.2.0.0.nupkg.sha512]
    Skipping... match hash failed
  Considering entry [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll] and probe dir [/packagescache]
The hash file is invalid [/packagescache/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.0.0/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.2.0.0.nupkg.sha512]
    Skipping... match hash failed
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.0.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
```

Comment: posibly related?  how did you publish?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796439/how-to-include-dependencies-in-net-core-app-docker-image?rq=1

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by executing the application found in the publish folder.  For instance, if you are publishing a .net core 1.1 app in release mode for Ubuntu 16.04, your published files will be in

> \bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\ubuntu.16.04-x64

This directory has an executable in it, but that is not the executable you want to use.  You actually need to go one directory deeper and use the executable in

> \bin\release\netcoreapp1.1\ubuntu.16.04-x64\publish

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running my aspnet core application in a Docker container. I had upgraded from Dotnet core 1.1 to aspnet core 2.

I had to change my Dockerfile base to use Microsoft/aspnet rather than Microsoft/Dotnet as Dotnet base didn't have all the aspnet libs.